# Fix java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity' for specific devices

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-9.0-pie

I get this in crashlytics.
I understand we could use AppCompat versions for theme. But why I'm getting this crash only for a certain device?
As of now, only one user, Having Android 9 Vivo phones.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```